# Highlighting the search phase IN sql

Tags: c++, css, sql, sql-server, vb.net

While it is easy to do replace of the the search text in the code after getting the dataset from an sql with a where clause:

```
x = x.Replace("SearchText","<span style='color:RED'>SearchText</span>");
```

I was wondering if there was a way to this IN the SQL.

```
Select x.Replace("SearchText","<span class='highlight'>SearchText</span>") as x from t where x like '%SearchText%'
```

or something like that.

The reason I am asking is because I do a:

```
COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName) as Name
```

and I don't want a returned Name field of "Bobbly, Bob" to get two highlighted areas when searching for a LastName that includes "Bob" or a FirstName that includes "Bob" (Noting that first and last names have different search phrases"

Yeah, I could just return the two field separately and join them in code, but I just want to see if it can be done in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T-SQL includes a Replace Function

REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )

That should do what you need

```
COALESCE(REPLACE(FirstName,'SearchText1','<span class=''highlight''>' + 'SearchText1' + '</span>')+','
        +REPLACE(LastName,'SearchText2','<span class=''highlight''>'+'SearchText2'+'</span>')
        ,REPLACE(FirstName,'SearchText1','<span class=''highlight''>' + 'SearchText1' + '</span>')
        ,REPLACE(LastName,'SearchText2','<span class=''highlight''>'+'SearchText2'+'</span>')
        ,'')
```